# commenting and puting legends on the side of axis, particular case of multiple axes :

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, graphics, scatter-plot

Here is my problem. I would love to scatter plot from other data than in this working example, two scatter plots, on the same figure, with two different axis (each scaled greatly for the data). 
I almost succeed, here is the result :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
fig.tight_layout
ax = plt.axes()
ax_bis = ax.twinx()

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y1 = dist1 = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.25, 100)
y2 = dist2 = np.random.normal(8, 0.1, 100)


plt.grid(True)
lns1 = ax.plot(x,y1, 'ro', label = 'dist 1' )
lns2 = ax_bis.plot(x,y2, 'yx', label = 'dist 2')


lns = lns1+lns2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax.legend(lns, labs, loc = "upper left")

#plt.text(50, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
#ax_bis.xlabel('Time')

plt.suptitle('my graph')
```

[image]

> my struggle is with this : I can't name the axis. The classical ways
>   don't function (I put them in the code as comments) and I would love
>   to put some comments on the graph itself (like a small text saying :
>   "hey ! the graph is great"). How could one do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close to setting the label and getting your text.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
fig.tight_layout
ax = plt.axes()
ax_bis = ax.twinx()

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y1 = dist1 = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.25, 100)
y2 = dist2 = np.random.normal(8, 0.1, 100)


plt.grid(True)
lns1 = ax.plot(x,y1, 'ro', label = 'dist 1' )
lns2 = ax_bis.plot(x,y2, 'yx', label = 'dist 2')


lns = lns1+lns2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax.legend(lns, labs, loc = "upper left")

# EDITS
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.text(0,0.6,"Hello World") # x,y,message
#plt.text(50, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
#ax_bis.xlabel('Time')

plt.suptitle('my graph')
```

NOTE: Your plot is a

```
'AxesSubplot' object
```

and does not have the attribute .xlabel but rather has .set_xlabel

You can set the text with (pseudocode)

```
ax.text(xval,yval,message)
```

Here is the result.
[image]